# Tic Tac Toe program output statements and functions

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

For this program I'm supposed to create a tic tac toe game and so far I've got this but I'm not sure how to write who wins and how to make it so that the players can't overwrite each other's moves if the row/col is already taken.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Locations(int &, int &);
void Tables(char [][3], int);

int main()
{
    const int cRow = 3;
    const int cCol = 3;
    char table[cRow][cCol] = { '-', '-', '-',
        '-', '-', '-',
        '-', '-', '-'};
    int nRow, nCol;


    Tables(table, cRow);



    for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (count < 5) {
            cout << "\n Player X";
            Locations(nRow, nCol);
            table[nRow][nCol] = 'X';
            Tables(table, cRow);
        }

        if (count < 4) {
            cout << "\n Player O";
            Locations(nRow, nCol);
            table[nRow][nCol] = 'O';
            Tables(table, cRow);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}

void Locations(int &nRow, int &nCol) {
    cout << " please enter row (0 to 2): ";
    cin >> nRow;
    while(nRow < 0 || nRow > 2)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry\n";
        cout << " please enter row (0 to 2): ";
        cin >> nRow;
    }
    cout << " please enter col (0 to 2): ";
    cin >> nCol;
    while(nCol < 0 || nCol > 2)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry\n";
        cout << " please enter col (0 to 2): ";
        cin >> nCol;
    }
}

void Tables(char table[][3], int nRow) {
    for(int iRow = 0; iRow < nRow; iRow++)
    {
        for(int iCol = 0; iCol < 3; iCol++)
        {
            cout << " " << table[iRow][iCol];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if a square is empty when the user enters a column and row (you could check if that matrix has a value of O or X (what I would recommend) or create a flag variable for each matrix element).  Maybe create a simple function that checks for X, O, or -, then call it within your Locations function.  Something like if the element contains "-", return true could work.  For announcing the winner, you could create another simple function that checks for winning patterns and call it after each player occupies a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing too much of your program you can have a function to check for a winner and an array to check for occupied positions:

```
// Prototypes
void check_for_winner(char [][3], bool&, bool&);

bool taken[3][3]; // to mark positions as taken
```

In main you can have two `bool`'s to decide a winner:

```
bool x_wins = false;
bool o_wins = false;
```

And in your `for loop` you can check for the winner after each move:

```
for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
{
   if (count < 5) {
      cout << "\n Player X";
      Locations(nRow, nCol);
      table[nRow][nCol] = 'X';
      Tables(table, cRow);
      check_for_winner(table, x_wins, o_wins); // Check for winner
      if (x_wins || o_wins) break;             // break if there is one
   }

   if (count < 4) {
      cout << "\n Player O";
      Locations(nRow, nCol);
      table[nRow][nCol] = 'O';
      Tables(table, cRow);
      check_for_winner(table, x_wins, o_wins); // Check for winner
      if (x_wins || o_wins) break;             // break if there is one
   }
}

// Output winner/draw
if (x_wins) cout << "\nX Wins!\n";
else if (o_wins) cout << "\nO Wins!\n";
else cout << "\nIt's a draw!\n";
```

In your `Locations` function:

```
void Locations(int &nRow, int &nCol) {
   bool stop = false;
   while (!stop) {
      cout << " please enter row (0 to 2): ";
      cin >> nRow;
      cout << " please enter col (0 to 2): ";
      cin >> nCol;

      // If position is invalid
      if (nRow < 0 || nRow > 2 || nCol < 0 || nCol > 2) {
         cout << "Invalid position, try again\n";
         continue;
      }
      else if (taken[nRow][nCol]) {
         cout << "Position taken, try again\n";
      }
      else { // success
         stop = true;
         taken[nRow][nCol] = true; // Mark position as taken
      }
   }
}
```

The function that checks for a winner checks horizontally, vertically and diagonally:

```
void check_for_winner(char table[][3], bool& x_wins, bool& o_wins)
{
   // check horizontally
   for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x) {
      for (int y = 0, occur_x = 0, occur_o = 0; y != 3; ++y) {
         if (table[x][y] == 'X') ++occur_x;
         else if (table[x][y] == 'O') ++occur_o;

         if (occur_x == 3) {
            x_wins = true;
            return;
         }
         if (occur_o == 3) { 
            o_wins = true;
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   // Check vertically
   for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x) {
      for (int y = 0, occur_x = 0, occur_o = 0; y != 3; ++y) {
         if (table[y][x] == 'X') ++occur_x;
         else if (table[y][x] == 'O') ++occur_o;

         if (occur_x == 3) {
            x_wins = true;
            return;
         }
         if (occur_o == 3) { 
            o_wins = true;
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   // Check diagonally top left->bottom right
   for (int x = 0, y = 0, occur_x = 0, occur_o = 0; x != 3; ++x, ++y) {
      if (table[x][y] == 'X') ++occur_x;
      else if (table[x][y] == 'O') ++occur_o;

      if (occur_x == 3) {
         x_wins = true;
         return;
      }
      if (occur_o == 3) {
         o_wins = true;
         return;
      }
   }

   // Check diagonally top right->bottoml left
   for (int x = 2, y = 0, occur_x = 0, occur_o = 0; x != -1; --x, ++y) {
      if (table[x][y] == 'X') ++occur_x;
      else if (table[x][y] == 'O') ++occur_o;

      if (occur_x == 3) {
         x_wins = true;
         return;
      }
      if (occur_o == 3) {
         o_wins = true;
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that if a tile has any `char` other than `-` then a player cannot write into that tile because someone must have already taken it. You can also write a function that tests if either player has won yet by looping through each row, column, and diagonal to see if there are three `X`'s or `O`'s in a row.

That would be a brute force approach but since we're talking about a 3x3 matrix it wouldn't matter if it is inefficient.